# Can I use RGB in python's graphics module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

I'm using python's graphics module. Can I use RGB to define colors or do I have to use its name?

Normal color setfill:

```
point.setFill('white')
```

What I want to do:

```
point.setFill(255, 255, 255)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html#custom-colors), the answer is: yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `color_rgb()` to convert the rgb integers into a parameter `setFill()` can use:

```
point.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))
```